# Why do I get CORS error when CORS is already allowing all?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

We've been getting this error on our developer workstations forever:

> Font from origin 'http://localhost:65314' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:61450' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

We have three IIS Express sites running in tandem, all of them are set up with

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

I've tried going through all the controller classes and adding:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
```

I saw no effect in the response header until I added this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Now the response headers show:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

I tried also adding this since the font is static content:

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

But the error remains. Using IIS Express 8.

The font is somehow getting loaded anyway, though--the Network tab shows that a 200 success is happening at some point getting the referenced woff2 file.

I want to get rid of this error from the Chrome debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to Register method of WebApiConfig.cs :

```
var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:65314,http://localhost:61450", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
```

If the error still persists then try by removing below setting from web.config

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: We're not using Web API in this context. (We are using it elsewhere but not on the site requesting the font and not on the site providing the font.) Also we're using OWIN / IAppBuilder not GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.